# Android Studio: loading file from local directory for testing

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio

I would like to load a bitmap from my PC's C:\Dev folder for testing purposes. However when I try a trivial path check:

```
File file = new File("C:/Dev/");
boolean exists = file.exists();
```

I get exists = false. I've also tried the same with escape characters for Windows' style paths:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Dev\\");
boolean exists = file.exists();
```

but still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance,

Riz

Comment: I don't understand your question. You making app for android ? And want to access resources from PC?

Comment: I wanted to have some test images available in the app when I ran tests. These happen to be sitting on my PC and I wanted to somehow make them available to my app for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your folder into assets. So basically create in src\androidTest
folder assets and there put your files.

To get access to those files, you must call context.getAssets()... where context is your activity for example. Then rest is just normal file reading with inputstream etc.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for such a quick reply - works like a charm. I will just add for those looking at this, context.getAssets(.) doesn't work if extending AndroidTestCase, need to extend something with Instrumentation.